# Integrating bessel function with 2 variables

Tags: python, lambda, integration

I'm having trouble executing this code and I suspect this is a problem caused by using the lambda function with multiple variables inside the bessel function J1. The function q(theta) is giving an error. INTEGRATEZI is just an integration method (Gauss-Kronrod method) from 0 to 10**10.

```
from scipy.special import j1 as J1
from cmath import sin, cos
import scipy
from scipy import array


def cml(function):
    return (scipy.real(function)**2 - scipy.imag(function)**2)

def quad_routine(func, a, b, x_list, w_list):
    c_1 = (b-a)/2.0
    c_2 = (b+a)/2.0
    eval_points = map(lambda x: c_1*x+c_2, x_list)
    func_evals = map(func, eval_points)
    return c_1 * sum(array(func_evals) * array(w_list))

def quad_kronrod_15(func, a, b):
    x_kr = [-0.991455371120813,-0.949107912342759, -0.864864423359769, -0.741531185599394, -0.586087235467691,-0.405845151377397, -0.207784955007898, 0.0, 0.207784955007898,0.405845151377397, 0.586087235467691, 0.741531185599394, 0.864864423359769, 0.949107912342759, 0.991455371120813]
    w_kr = [0.022935322010529, 0.063092092629979, 0.104790010322250, 0.140653259715525, 0.169004726639267, 0.190350578064785, 0.204432940075298, 0.209482141084728, 0.204432940075298, 0.190350578064785, 0.169004726639267, 0.140653259715525,  0.104790010322250, 0.063092092629979, 0.022935322010529]
    return quad_routine(func,a,b,x_kr, w_kr)

class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.eval_points = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.eval_points:
            self.eval_points[args] = self.func(*args)
        return self.eval_points[args]

def quadt(func,a,b):
    func = Memoize(func) #  Memoize function to skip repeated function calls.
    k15 = quad_kronrod_15(func,a,b)
    return k15

def INTEGRATEZI(func, **kwargs):       # INTEGRATEZI short for Integrating from zero to infinity
    def real_func(x):
        return scipy.real(func(x))
    def imag_func(x):
        return scipy.imag(func(x))
    real_integral = quadt(real_func, 0, 10**10)
    imag_integral = quadt(imag_func, 0, 10**10)
    return (real_integral + 1j*imag_integral)
r = 2.0
p = lambda theta: r*sin(theta)
z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
print q(0.5)
```

Here's the error report:

```
%run "C:/Users/ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE/Documents/University/Year 3/project/123123.py"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195             else:
    196                 filename = fname
--> 197             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198     else:
    199         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in <module>()
     45 z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
     46 q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
---> 47 print q(0.5)

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in <lambda>(theta)
     44 p = lambda theta: r*sin(theta)
     45 z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
---> 46 q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
     47 print q(0.5)

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in INTEGRATEZI(func, **kwargs)
     38     def imag_func(x):
     39         return scipy.imag(func(x))
---> 40     real_integral = quadt(real_func, 0, 10**10)
     41     imag_integral = quadt(imag_func, 0, 10**10)
     42     return (real_integral + 1j*imag_integral)

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in quadt(func, a, b)
     30 def quadt(func,a,b):
     31     func = Memoize(func) #  Memoize function to skip repeated function calls.
---> 32     k15 = quad_kronrod_15(func,a,b)
     33     return k15
     34 

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in quad_kronrod_15(func, a, b)
     17     x_kr = [-0.991455371120813,-0.949107912342759, -0.864864423359769, -0.741531185599394, -0.586087235467691,-0.405845151377397, -0.207784955007898, 0.0, 0.207784955007898,0.405845151377397, 0.586087235467691, 0.741531185599394, 0.864864423359769, 0.949107912342759, 0.991455371120813]
     18     w_kr = [0.022935322010529, 0.063092092629979, 0.104790010322250, 0.140653259715525, 0.169004726639267, 0.190350578064785, 0.204432940075298, 0.209482141084728, 0.204432940075298, 0.190350578064785, 0.169004726639267, 0.140653259715525,  0.104790010322250, 0.063092092629979, 0.022935322010529]
---> 19     return quad_routine(func,a,b,x_kr, w_kr)
     20 
     21 class Memoize(object):

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in quad_routine(func, a, b, x_list, w_list)
     11     c_2 = (b+a)/2.0
     12     eval_points = map(lambda x: c_1*x+c_2, x_list)
---> 13     func_evals = map(func, eval_points)
     14     return c_1 * sum(array(func_evals) * array(w_list))
     15 

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in __call__(self, *args)
     25     def __call__(self, *args):
     26         if args not in self.eval_points:
---> 27             self.eval_points[args] = self.func(*args)
     28         return self.eval_points[args]
     29 

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in real_func(x)
     35 def INTEGRATEZI(func, **kwargs):       # INTEGRATEZI short for Integrating from zero to infinity
     36     def real_func(x):
---> 37         return scipy.real(func(x))
     38     def imag_func(x):
     39         return scipy.imag(func(x))

C:\Users\ENVY14-i7-SPECTRE\Documents\University\Year 3\project\123123.py in <lambda>(kp)
     44 p = lambda theta: r*sin(theta)
     45 z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
---> 46 q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
     47 print q(0.5)

TypeError: ufunc 'j1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because the argument you provide to the Bessel function:

```
kp * p(theta)
```

is not a real number. Scipy then throws a type error because it is expecting a real number.

Why is it not real? You're using python's complex number math library, `cmath`, whose `sin` function returns results as complex numbers. So, for example,

```
In [9]: cmath.sin(.5)
Out[9]: (0.479425538604203+0j)
```

has a (zero) imaginary component. But Scipy's Bessel function receives a variable of complex type and doesn't know what to do with it. The quick fix is to use the standard `math` library, or replace `r*sin(theta)` by `r*sin(theta).real` and `r*cos(theta)` by `r*cos(theta).real` in the definitions of `p` and `q`.

---

To see this, you can use a tool like the [python debugger](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/debugging/#using-the-python-debugger) to find exactly why an exception is raised. It looks like you're using IPython, which has some easy-to-use debugging tools included.

In your case, run your code at the IPython terminal, and you'll get an exception:

```
In [4]: run code.py

     ... (cut for space) ...

     45 p = lambda theta: r*sin(theta)
     46 z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
---> 47 q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
     48 print q(0.5)
TypeError: ufunc 'j1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

You'll see that a `TypeError` has been raised when evaluating the line with the `--->`. But there's a lot going on in this line. What exactly caused the problem?

A simple way to check is to launch into the debugger "post-mortem". The values of each variable are "frozen" in time as they were when the exception occurs, so we can poke around and see what the problem might have been.

Right after running your code and seeing the exception, type `%debug` at the IPython prompt:

```
In [5]: %debug
> /home/eldridge/sandbox/stack/stack.py(47)<lambda>()
     46 z = lambda theta: r*cos(theta)
---> 47 q = lambda theta: (p(theta) + z(theta) + INTEGRATEZI(lambda kp: (J1(kp * p(theta))) ))
     48 print q(0.5)
```

We're in the frame that caused the error. You thought the issue might be with the Bessel function, so I decided to ask what the argument was. You can use the `p` command to print a variable:

```
ipdb> p kp
42723144.39593506
```

That looks fine. What about `p(theta)`?

```
ipdb> p p(theta)
(0.958851077208406+0j)
```

Hm. It's imaginary. Can the Bessel function handle complex input? I can't remember my math courses, but I can try it out and see:

```
ipdb> p J1(1j)
*** TypeError: TypeError("ufunc 'j1' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''",)
```

Apparently not.

There's a lot more to the debugger, of course, and it's worth checking out a [tutorial](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/debugging/#using-the-python-debugger) when you have some time.

Comment: I can't believe I made such a grave mathematical mistake! Upon changing the type of sin and cos from the cmath version to the math version to obtain a real number for bessel function, it works! Thanks jme!